# how much time a Magento team will take to check submitted extension?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to know that Generally..how much time a Magento team will take to check submitted extension ? And within how many days after submitted my extension i get reply from magento team about my extension status...??

Answer (score 0):

You should get a reply from them **within a week**. But this will also depend on how many extension submission request are in queue.

The Magento team checks the following main things:

1. Extension Description
2. Screenshot
3. Extension Icon
4. Extension logic as how it will be useful.

Based on that they will reply on your registered mail id.